# Garbage DNS record

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

nslookup returns 2 IP addresses for one of the clients in my network:

```
Server:  dc.mynet.local
Address:  192.168.43.1

Name:    fileserver.mynet.local
Addresses:  192.168.43.2
          192.168.45.2
```

My DNS server have no "192.168.45.2" record, at least I can't find it. This garbage record, I suppose, is the reason of the "RPC server not available" error that I often get when trying to connect TO FILESERVER via RDC. This error can be temporarily fixed by restarting DNS client service on FILESERVER.

How to clean this record out of the DNS server?

Comment: Two A records is valid. If you want help with your DNS server you'll have to tell us what server you're using and post relevant details, such as the configuration that describes any local DNS entries.

Comment: If 192.168.45.2 isn't valid then simply delete it.

Comment: I know that multiple A records may be valid. But not in my case. I use DNS server that is running on the DC (Windows 2003 Server virtual machine on the Hyper-V host). This server has 2 network adapters: 192.168.43.1 (connected to LAN) and 192.168.45.1 (connected to Hyper-V internal network). FILESERVER is a virtual machine on the same Hyper-V host and has 2 similar network adapters with adresses 192.168.43.2 and 192.168.45.2. No DNS server is specified for 192.168.45.2, but it was specified before (that's how the 2nd A record appeared).

Comment: Well it's strange but now I can see the corresponding A record in DNS server console. I deleted it, and now nslookup shows only one address for FILESERVER. Hard to tell where the record came from as it surely was lacking before.

Comment: I believe I got it. I did everything (clearing DNS cache, restarting DNS server) except refreshing DNS server console contents by pressing F5. That's why I didn't see the records that actually were there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the DNS Manager MMC snap-in (dnsmgmt.msc)
2. Connect to DNS server on DC.mynet.local (if running dnsmgmt.msc from a machine other than DC.mynet.local)
3. Expand 'DC'
4. Expand 'Forward Lookup Zones'
5. Select 'mynet.local'
6. Right-click and delete record with the name 'FILESERVER', type 'Host (A)' and data '192.168.45.2'
7. Flush local DNS cache (ipconfig /flushdns) and retest

Comment: As I said, there's no record with the name 'FILESERVER', type 'Host (A)' and data '192.168.45.2' there. That's what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

What forwarders does the DNS server on DC use?

Have you cleared the cache for the DNS server on DC?

Comment: Also run dig so you can get more information than nslookup offers.

Comment: No forwarders, no root servers. It's an internal DNS server.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... all your workstations should have only the DC(s) set as DNS servers... if there are no forwarders on the DNS server it will have nowhere to recurse to provide clients records for names it is not authoritative for (e.g. serverfault.com). Did you actually check the properties of the DNS server?

Comment: All my clients have the DC as the first DNS server and the DNS forwarder on the Internet gate as the second DNS server. It allows them to have access to the Internet even if the DNS server on the DC is unavailable (not an often case but still).